# Get items from array within strings in Vue-resource

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm learning how to use Vue-Resource and I've hit a wall with the api I'm working with. I'm trying to set up a list of threads using `v-for: thread in threads`.

Here's a sample of what I'm working with:

```
[{
"threads": [{
    "no": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "com": "comment"
},{
    "no": 2,
    "name": "Jim",
    "com": "comment"
},{
    "no": 3,
    "name": "Jane",
    "com": "comment"
}],
"page": 0
}, {
"threads": [{
    "no": 4,
    "name": "Tom",
    "com": "comment"
},{
    "no": 5,
    "name": "Mark",
    "com": "comment"
}],
"page": 1
}]
```

The api has threads listed across a few pages, what I want is a list that looks something like `{{ thread.name }}{{ thread.com }}` for each `no` but I'm not entirely clear on how to grab that information using vue-resource. Currently if I use

```
<li v-for="thread in threads"> {{ thread.name }}{{ thread.com }} </li>
```

I just get a list of empty items.

Answer (score 0):

First off I added double quotes around the name values, and saved your JSON to a variable called pages.

```
var pages=[
  {
    "threads": [
      {
        "no": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "com": "comment"
      },
      {
        "no": 2,
        "name": "Jim",
        "com": "comment"
      },
      {
        "no": 3,
        "name": "Jane",
        "com": "comment"
      }
    ],
    "page": 0
  },
  {
    "threads": [
      {
        "no": 4,
        "name": "Tom",
        "com": "comment"
      },{
        "no": 5,
        "name": "Mark",
        "com": "comment"
      }
    ],
    "page": 1
  }
]
```

Then your HTML could look something like this

```
<div v-for:"page in pages">
  <div class="page" v-for"thread in page.threads">
    <div>{{thread.name}}{{thread.com}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I set it up this way when I'm getting an API? Here's my js: http://pastebin.com/6GxR8BdJ

Comment: My API.json works like the example posted in my question.